# Como utilizar \t (tabulação) nas saídas com EOF?

Tags: regex, shell

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
cat << EOF
alias\tVARIABLE = command
EOF
```

A saída de execução não leva em consideração o regex `\t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `cat` não interpreta os códigos de escape mas existem diversas formas de fazê-lo, uma delas é usar o **echo**:

```
echo -e "alias\tVARIABLE = command"
```

Que retornará a sequência `alias    VARIABLE = command` com a tabulação devidamente substituída.

Aliás é bom lembrar que por padrão o `echo` do **Bash** também não interpreta os escapes e precisa do parâmetro "-e" e que isto é desnecessário no caso do **Dash**.

Porém se você precisa realmente que a operação passe pelo `cat`, pode usar a substituição de processos:

```
cat <( echo -e "alias\tVARIABLE = command" )
```

Ou seja, a saída do `echo` será enviada para a entrada do `cat` como se fosse um arquivo de entrada (tal qual o `<<EOF ... EOF`).